# Could applications build in Xamarin possibly be banned from App Store by Apple?

Tags: legal, appstore, apple, xamarin, monodroid

Consider having restricted man resources and thinking about using Xamarin Studio for building cross platform application. Will you be afraid of Apple trying to ban all applications NOT developed by xCode? I mean in future. It is obviously not banned now.

I am just asking this because I heard this on a meeting today as argument of not using Xamarin studio. I am not an expert in this area but very curious because it sounds odd. The application should be banned because of some kind of generated code which is always there when building app using Xamarin.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the hypothetical future behavior of Apple.  See [Help Center, don't-ask](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Software development is also about thinking of maintenance, recurrent cost and so on. This kinds of decisions are very sensitive to final cost of the product (software). Looking for pros and cons of particular development tools; thinking of possible risks is not OFF TOPIC regarding software development. I am very happy, I got at least some feedback before it was put on hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple is not gonna ban an application if the application was developed outside of Xcode, however apple is gonna ban an app that doesn't follow the guidelines so if the tool you are using to develop applications creates code that comply with the apple guidelines you are pretty much safe.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Check them if you are registered as a developer.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not true. Apple will not ban Apps for compiling in Xamarin.

This is a myth that might have been spurred by Apple's history to revoke `HTML5` Apps when the store first opened. Since then Apple is now accepting those types of Apps, and has been for a long time. Keep in mind that Facebook (one of the stores most popular apps) was once written in HTML5.

Anyone who is advising you that Xamarin is not an option because it will get banned by Apple has no clue what the app requires are for the store.

Follow Apple's Guidelines and you'll be fine.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Comment: Apple *does* have a history of enforcing non-written rules, especially regarding "using stuff that's not ours". *And* they have a history of *changing* those guidelines (not just negatively: when a sh*tstorm hits, they might even change it in a good way!). So saying "Apple will not ban *X*" is ... a gutsy move.

Comment: When the SDK originally came out, one of the requirements was that you build apps with Xcode, not with third party frameworks.  Apple has since backed down on that, and will allow anything in as long as it meets their standards for being a quality app (and even there it gives leeway).  So it's unlikely they'll go backwards on this.

Comment: @AlanShutko: that last sentence I can understand. But a plain "they will not ban" is hardly arguable, in my opinion.

Comment: True. It is never wise to speak in absolutes about Apple's future actions.

Comment: thank you, I would vote you up but don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: @AlanShutko only a sith deal in absolutes

Comment: I have no interest in providing someone with an ambiguous "maybe" answer for a question that is fear based or the product of popular myth. The answer will remain **No** unless someone can come here with credible evidence that an app was rejected purely on the grounds of being created with Xamarin. Deciding on what platform to base your app on is an important decision, and including myths as facts in your decision process is wrong. The discussion on the *future* of Xamarin is a different topic, and not what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 3):

There was wording in the Developers Agreement for a while to the effect that Apple has the right to reject any code not developed using XCode...but that was targeted specifically at Flash. Xamarin code compiles to native iOS binaries where as Adobe's solution with flash used an interpreter which was slow. That was the meat of the problem.

Comment: thank you, I would vote you up but don't have enough reputation points.